# How to install TestNG plugin in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, testng

I want to use Visual Studio Code for my java project which uses TestNG as the testing framework. How to achieve this.

Comment: This should help you, feature you are asking for was added 15 days ago: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-test